# Field of a structure changing randomly and i cant find the issue

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#define MAX_LINE  80

int historyLength=10;
int currentNumberOfHistoryElements=0;
int currentCommandNumber=1;
int notDone=1;
size_t n=MAX_LINE;

struct pastCommand
{

    char *command;
    char *commandslist[10];
    int commandlistLength;
};

void addNewHistory(struct pastCommand *newHistory,struct pastCommand *historyList[])
{
    char *look = newHistory->command;
    printf("HEREsad %s\n",look );
    if(currentNumberOfHistoryElements<historyLength)
    {
        for(int i=0; i<historyLength; i++)
        {
            if(historyList[i]==NULL)
            {
                historyList[i]=newHistory;
                currentNumberOfHistoryElements++;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for(int i=0; i<historyLength-1; i++)
        {
            historyList[i+1]=historyList[i];
        }

        historyList[0]=newHistory;
    }
}

void printHelp()
{
    printf("List of Commands:\n Verbose[on|off]: shows info as commands called \n help: what you are looking at right now\n history: the past 10 commands you have entered\n quit: quit the program\n");
}

void printHistoryElement(struct pastCommand *currentHistory, int number)
{
    if(currentHistory==NULL)
    {


    }
    else
    {
        int myLength=currentHistory->commandlistLength;
        char *myCommand=currentHistory->command;
        printf("LOOKIE %s\n",myCommand);

        printf("Commands #%d: %s\n",number, myCommand);
        for(int i=0; i<myLength; i++)
        {

            printf("arg[%d] :%s\n",i,currentHistory->commandslist[i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

void printHistory(struct pastCommand *allHistories[],int length)
{
    for(int i=0; i<length; i++)
    {
        printHistoryElement(allHistories[i],i);
    }
}

void freeHistoryList(struct pastCommand *allHistories[])
{
    for(int i=0; i< historyLength; i++)
    {
        if(allHistories[i]!=NULL)
        {
            free(allHistories[i]);
        }
    }
}

void runProgram()
{
    struct pastCommand *allCommands[historyLength];
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        allCommands[i]=NULL;
    }
    char* buf = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * MAX_LINE);

    while(notDone)
    {
        printf("mish[%d]> ",currentCommandNumber);

        int result=getline(&buf, &n, stdin);
        if(result==-1)
        {
            printf("\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        else
        {
            strtok(buf,"\n");
            if(strcmp(buf,"help")==0)
            {
                printHelp();
                struct pastCommand *current=malloc(sizeof(struct pastCommand));
                current->command=malloc(sizeof(buf));

                current->command=buf;
                printf("%s\n",current->command );
                current->commandlistLength=0;
                addNewHistory(current,allCommands);
                printf("HIT IT\n");
            }
            else if(strcmp(buf,"quit")==0)
            {
                free(buf);
                freeHistoryList(allCommands);
                exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
            }
            else if(strcmp(buf,"history")==0)
            {
                printHistory(allCommands,currentNumberOfHistoryElements);
            }
        }

        currentCommandNumber++;
    }
}

int mish_command_name(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    runProgram();
    return 0;
}
```

Overall the issue is I'm keeping a history of commands that are to be run. When I type `help`, it works fine and I see `help` is added to the history list with the command name `help`. However, when I type `history` to show it, the command name which is being printed changes to `history` which is really weird.

I tried to debug as you can see from the code and I have no idea how the field variable for the structure is changing from `help` to `history`. If I type `help` like 5 times, then type `history`, all the command names have the name `history`.

Some insight would be incredibly helpful.

Comment: Please post the relevant code in the body of your question instead of linking to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a problem with:

```
current->command=buf;
```

`buf` is the buffer allocated by `getline`, however that function will re-use its buffer each time (and maybe even `free` it if it needed to reallocate), so it is not a good idea to have your commands point to that buffer. You should `malloc` new space for each command.

It looks like you tried that with:

```
current->command=malloc(sizeof(buf));
```

however (as well as mallocing the wrong number of bytes) you never actually use that malloc'd space, you just pointed `current->command` at `buf` immediately after.

Try replacing both lines with:

```
current->command = strdup(buf);
```